# PHP Secure Session and user login

Tags: php, security, session, hash

I want to create an authentication system that allows users to login to a secure area of the website.

Ive been doing some reading and have decided to hash and salt using the supplied php class from

> https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

I was also thinking about encrypting the session data using the php class from here

> http://www.zimuel.it/encrypt-php-session-data/

and

> https://github.com/ezimuel/PHP-Secure-Session

I will be using PDO and sanitizing my outputs. Basic SSL will be on and `CAPCHA's` on the login forms.

I was wondering if their is anything else that anyone can recommend to secure the session and security of the site.

The secure area will be a php frontend to a database (`CRM`)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you thinking about encrypting the session data? (Not saying that you shouldn't, but I get the impression that you're thinking about doing it because you've seen it, rather than understanding why you'd want to do it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The author of the CrackStation article](https://defuse.ca) is a good friend of mine, so let me provide a bit of historical context: **It was written before `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` landed in PHP 5.5**. What this means is you should, instead, just use what PHP gives you. (And if you're on an older version of PHP, upgrade.) Incidentally, PHP 5.5 also offered `hash_pbkdf2()`, but `hash_equals()` didn't arrive until 5.6.

As luck would have it, I do happen to have a blog post that addresses [PHP session security](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions) in detail.